# weird error i cannot get my head around in pearsonr function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

my code is like below:

```
predict_n=model.predict(x_test)
predict_n=predict_n.astype(np.float64)
corr_value, p_value = pearsonr(predict_n, y_test)   
print(corr_value,round(p_value,4))
print(esc('31;1;4') +"correlation:"+corr_value+" p_value:"+p_value)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 30))
plot_corr(val_d[:,i,j], predict_n[:,i,j],corrs[i,j])
```

and when it hits the 3rd row it outputs this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b71eb959e83c> in <module>
     66     predict_n=model.predict(x_test)
     67     predict_n=predict_n.astype(np.float64)
---> 68     corr_value, p_value = pearsonr(predict_n, y_test)
     69     print(corr_value,round(p_value,4))
     70     print(esc('31;1;4') +"correlation:"+corr_value+" p_value:"+p_value)

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in pearsonr(x, y)
   3517         return dtype(np.sign(x[1] - x[0])*np.sign(y[1] - y[0])), 1.0
   3518 
-> 3519     xmean = x.mean(dtype=dtype)
   3520     ymean = y.mean(dtype=dtype)
   3521 

~\Anaconda3\envs\deeplearning\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    149             is_float16_result = True
    150 
--> 151     ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
    152     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
    153         ret = um.true_divide(

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add
```

This error i found on this site has to do with variable type. Thats why i added the second row above to make them both to float64. when i, for example input

```
print(np.shape(predict_n))
print(np.shape(y_test))
print(predict_n.dtype)
print(y_test.dtype)
```

iget the output

```
(367, 100, 1)
(367, 100, 1)
float64
float64
```

Can anyone pls help figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

The shapes of your inputs are (367, 100, 1).  [`pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) requires the inputs to be 1-d arrays¹.  Unfortunately, that cryptic error message provides no help for figuring out what is wrong!

If your intent is to treat each input as a 1-d sequence of 36700 values, you can use `pearsonr(predict_n.ravel(), y_test.ravel())`.

If you expected `pearsonr` to implicitly loop over one of the dimensions, you'll have to write your own loop to do that.

---

¹ Eventually `pearsonr` will be enhanced with an `axis` argument, but for now, its inputs must be 1-d.